# How to approximate the sum of a convergent, positive series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}$$

This series converges because the general term goes to $0$ faster than $\dfrac1{n^2}$

I am asked to approximate the series with an error $R<10^{-3}$.

How can I do this? I know that

$$R=\left\lvert S-S_k\right\rvert=\left\lvert \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}\right\rvert=\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}$$ and that

$$\int_{k+1}^\infty \frac1{e^x(x^2+1)}\mathrm dx\le\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}\leq\int_{k}^\infty \frac1{e^x(x^2+1)}\mathrm dx$$

**My attempt:**

$$R=\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}\le\frac1{(k+1)^2+1}\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n}\underbrace\le_{(1)}\frac1{(k+1)^2+1}\int_k^\infty \frac1{e^x}\mathrm dx= \frac1{(k+1)^2+1}\frac1{e^k}<10^{-3}\quad (*)$$

$(1):$ as the series is decreasing, positive and continuous, I can switch to the integral.

$(*)$ is true for $k=4$.

Is this a right approach?

P.S. The exercise comes from *Calculus Problems*, 16.18, page 231.

Comment: what is $f(x)?$

Comment: @zhw. $f(n)=a_n$. Edited the question accordingly

Comment: You don't need the integral since $\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n}=\frac1{e^{k+1}(1-1/e)}$.

Comment: I just realized that this is a geometrical series, so the integral was not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easily computable upper bound is

$$R
=\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n(n^2+1)}
\lt \frac1{(k+1)^2}\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac1{e^n}
=\frac1{(k+1)^2e^{k+1}(1-1/e)}$$

Comment: Is my upper bound acceptable?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to be as elementary as possible, so no integrals.

Comment: Would any upper bound be acceptable or not?